# Removing GraphHighlight from highlighted graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

What is the problem with the following code? Annotation `GraphHighlight` should be deleted but it is still present in the graph:

```
g = HighlightGraph[CompleteGraph[5], PathGraph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1}]];
AnnotationValue[g, GraphHighlight]
g = AnnotationDelete[g, GraphHighlight];
AnnotationValue[g, GraphHighlight]
Clear[g]
(*{2\[UndirectedEdge]3,1,5,5\[UndirectedEdge]1,1\[UndirectedEdge]2,2,4\[UndirectedEdge]5,3\[UndirectedEdge]4,4,3}*)
(*{2\[UndirectedEdge]3,1,5,5\[UndirectedEdge]1,1\[UndirectedEdge]2,2,3\[UndirectedEdge]4,4\[UndirectedEdge]5,3,4}*)
```

What is even stranger that annotation value changed order of the items in the output instead of deleting.

Comment: That does seem strange... Deleting all annotations using `AnnotationDelete[g]` does work at least, as does deleting it off individual elements, e.g. `AnnotationDelete[{g, 1}, GraphHighlight]`

Comment: I would call this a bug. Have you reported it to Wolfram (and also asked for a workaround)?

Comment: "(and also asked for a workaround)" - Whether I asked Wolfram or this site for workaround? I am tired of reporting to Wolfram, every now and then I find a bug. Easier would be if Wolfram watched the tag `bugs` here and honesty if they are not doing so I doubt any report to them has any sense. Where they can find more relevant source of bugs than here on this site, where many very competent people judge possibility of a bug?